# Is it right to import for argument typing in typescript?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typescript

I just started to use typescript and I am trying to get used to it.
I'm building a webapp using nodejs, postgresql and I want to connect to postgresql for querying but I am stuck at argument typing.

I have installed `@types/pg` so I thought it would

```
//import { PoolClient, QueryResult, Pool } from "pg"


var { pool } = require("./database/connectionPool")

pool.connect().then((client: PoolClient) => {
  client.query('SELECT * FROM "USER_CONFIDENTIAL"').then((err, res) => {
    client.release()
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
    console.log(res)
  })
})
```

In `pool.connect().then((client: PoolClient)`, I specified `client` to be `PoolClient` but it outputs `Cannot find name "PoolClient"` if I comment import.

1. Is it right to always import the types that I use in function arguments?
2. Also, how am I supposed to know the types of function arguments?

Comment: 1. Yes, that's why you get an error if you don't. 2. Read the docs/typings.

Comment: 1. thanks!
2. Do you mean that I need to browse through docs of libraries that I use everytime?